# How do I query for elasticsearch documents with exact field1 match and non-empty field2 match

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in elasticsearch with `field1` mapped to an integer value and `field2` mapped to an array.  I would like to create a query to find all documents with `field1 == 100` and `field2` is not empty.

How do I write such a query?

Comment: I am also in the same problem and one more thing that elasticsearch documentation is not good to explain a real-life problem. Thy need to update there doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) to match `field1` to value `100` and use [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to check if `field2` exists (not empty). Both the above conditions are AND so wrap them in `must` clause of [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Update based on the comment by @Val:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "field1": 100
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "field2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Quick note: @QuincyBowers since you're not interested in ranking but only filtering, consider using `filter` instead of `must`. The difference is not big on small data sets but definitely on big ones.

Comment: Agreed on what @Val mentioned. Query can be used in two contexts one `query` when you want to rank result docs and `filter` context when you just want to filter results and not interested in ranking. More on it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html).